wedge in a service to ensure a subsequent service is run after a service on another computer is running
I have a service on my RPi (MySensors Gateway mysgw) that I would like to start after Home Assistant (HA) is online.  HA is running in a virtual box running on another computer (Ubuntu 20.04).
Home Assistant will publish a message (online) to an MQTT broker when it is fully online.  It takes about 7 minutes from cold start to online
This can be detected with this script running on the RPi:  (note that the request to the MQTT broker will get error messages, like "not available"; these are ignored.)
# wait 5 seconds (-W 5) in the attempt to get 1 line of output (-C 1) data from the MQTT broker topic "homeassistant/status" and don't print out any error messages.    
while [ "$(mosquitto_sub -h $MQTThost -t homeassistant/status -C 1 -W 5 --quiet)" !=  "online" ]
    do
      sleep 15
    done

where $MQTThost is the intermediary between mysgw and HA.
What I would like to do is make this script a service and the mysgw.service runs after this script is completed
I could put this code in the file /usr/local/bin/mysgwWait4HA.sh and create the service header /etc/systemd/system/mysgwWait4HA.service which has the contents:
[Unit]
Description=Waits for Home Assistant to be online
Requires=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/mysgwWait4HA.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

and in the [Unit] section of /etc/systemd/system/mysgw.service, add to the Requires line, mysgwWait4HA.  eg:
Requires=network.target mysgwWait4HA

The part I don't understand is that this new service will terminate.  Will the mysgw.service start when this new service starts?  It seems that this new service needs to set a flag that indicates complete and that this flag indicates that the mysgw.service should now start.
What am I missing?
Thanks for your help
-OSD
